# Google Maps private nearby locations on route with directions api

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I have a database with about 5000 customers. All saved with lat/lng coordinates.

For our field personnel i have integrated the google maps directions api so that they can calculate the route from our headquarters to the chosen customer. That works perfect.

My problem is that i want to show all additional customers on that route. Has anyone ever done this before or has an idea on how to implement that? In my opinion the only way is to walk the returned array from google directions and do a nearby search with every waypoint.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the most sensible answer does indeed seem to be walking the array. Unless you are not tied into your specific database. In which case I would suggest looking [here at a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445109/how-best-to-perform-corridor-range-search-over-a-set-of-latitude-longitude-coo), and consider using a POSTGiS database. This will allow you to perform corridor range searches more easily.

If you are tied to a database then perhaps [this link](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/search-along-route-made-easy-with.html) will aid with the implementation of your solution. The library creates bounding boxes along the route within a distance to speed the querying process.

Comment: Hi Swires, RouteBoxer is exactly what i was looking for, because i'm tied to a MSSQL database. Thank you so much.